# Can't reference UILabel on Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uilabel

I have a class called cell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TokenCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *idlabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tokenlabel;

@end
```

In this app im trying to retrieve data from a server using Restkit, but this works right, the issue is more simple. I cant make a reference of this objects on Main.storyboard, XCode 5 just doesn't let me do this and the label properties that I created dont show in any way. I cant find where is the issue, so some help will be welcome. This Is very strange, because on my last test app I didn't have any problems doing this.

Comment: Sure you did not forget to set the correct class name in IB?

Comment: Did you check if your labels in the storyboard are connected to the IBOutlets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you've specified TokenCell as the custom class for your UITableView cells:

(Here are 2 images to illustrate - I can't show inline images as I am new to StackOverflow!)

[1. image - highlight the cell in your Main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNpo4.png)

[2. image - set the class to TokenCell, then save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVzrt.png)

Answer (score 2):

Just check you have given the class name in the storyboard file.
[image]